# How to show Group Header on each page with Crosstab All Page?

Tags: crystal-reports, header, report, crosstab

I have a report crosstab, First Page show Header with Crosstab from my text object (Tool).
But next page it's not show Header.

**Output:**

```
(First Page)
Position | EmpNo | FLName <<< Header
001 | 12316 | A
002 | 43621 | B

(Next Page) <<< No Header
003 | 43523 | C
004 | 05832 | D
```

**But I need result:**

```
(First Page)
Position | EmpNo | FLName <<< Header
001 | 12316 | A
002 | 43621 | B

(Next Page) 
Position | EmpNo | FLName <<< i need show Header all page
003 | 43523 | C
004 | 05832 | D
```

**My Report Crosstab**
[image: Report Crosstab]
I need show header all page, I try to set Group Expert > check 'Repeat Group Header On Each Page' but it doesn't work.

Comment: Put your "Group  #1 Name" into Page Header area.

Comment: But 'Group Expert > check 'Repeat Group Header On Each Page' did work for me, and that was what I was trying to find.  Thus the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Page Header section instead of the Group Header? As this will repeat on every page without tweaking any settings.

Now of course depending on your other content this may not work for your particular case, but it looks like you aren't using Details or the Page Header at the moment.